# Skipping lines in a file in c

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm trying to read to contents of a file, insert them into the fields of a structure, and print out the values. But it seems to ignore half of the patient's data because it skips a line containing data every time.

```
Sophia Jackson 1234 141.0 1.1 

Emma Aiden 5432 142.0 1.2

Olivia Lucas 5685 143.0 1.3

Ava Liam 5672 144.0 1.4

Mia Noah 3467 145.0 1.5

Isabella Ethan 8654 146.0 1.6

Riley Mason 2567 147.0 1.7

Aria Caden 6794 148.0 1.8
```

The names are formatted like so, except they aren't newlines in between each one

```
while(1) {
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %i %f %f",newptr->pfn,newptr->pln,&newptr->pid,&newptr->pwt,&newptr->phgnum);
        printf("First Name: %s\n",newptr->pfn);
        printf("Last Name: %s\n",newptr->pln);
        printf("PID: %i\n",newptr->pid);
        printf("Weight: %f\n",newptr->pwt);
        printf("HG1AC: %f\n",newptr->phgnum);

        if( 5 != fscanf(fp,"%s %s %i %f %f",newptr->pfn,newptr->pln,&newptr->pid,&newptr->pwt,&newptr->phgnum)) {
             break;
        }           
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of newptr

Comment: In your input file, is data `Sophia Jackson 1234 141.0 1.1 

Emma Aiden 5432 142.0 1.2` truly separated with a blank intervening line?

Comment: They aren't i'm trying to create a linked list using patient data from a file. So hope is to use fscanf to read the line, insert it into the fields, insert the patient into the linked list, and use some sort of terminating statement that will end the loop when it reaches an EOF. I two scanf's are sufficient for that, but skip a line every time, essentially erasing half of my data. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your second call to `fscanf()` reads the second line of data, overwriting the data previously read from the first line by the first `fscanf()`.

You need only one `fscanf()` within your loop.

Also, how are you setting/changing `newptr` within the loop?

**Addendum** (9 May 2018)

You should use only one `fscanf()` call within your loop. Furthermore, you should check the result of that call at the top of the loop to determine when you've hit EOF, and thus when to terminate the loop.

You could also call `feof()` to check for EOF before reading the next line.

Comment: I'm creating a linked list of the patients, I have that figured out. I just wanted to know how to read from a file. I'm using the second scaf so I know when the EOF is, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I added an addendum to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 fscanf function calls within the while loop. You consider the first one for displaying and the results of the second call just ignored. That means you ignore half from all data.

Following will solve the issue.

```
while(1){

        if( 5 != fscanf(fp,"%s %s %i %f %f",newptr->pfn,newptr->pln,&newptr->pid,&newptr->pwt,&newptr->phgnum)){
             break;
        }           

        printf("First Name: %s\n",newptr->pfn);
        printf("Last Name: %s\n",newptr->pln);
        printf("PID: %i\n",newptr->pid);
        printf("Weight: %f\n",newptr->pwt);
        printf("HG1AC: %f\n",newptr->phgnum);
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to take the data the from the line, insert it into a linked list, then re-write the newptr. So I need the initial fscanf to read the data, is there a way to terminate the loop when I reach an EOF that doesn't require a fscanf?